# "DataTables warning: Invalid JSON response" and "Error: Graph container element not found"

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables, morris.js

I am the developer of [bearpk.space](http://bearpk.space/). On my [`dashboard.php`](http://bearpk.space/dashboard.php) page (which you can't access, but whose source is [here](https://pastebin.com/3AAAPJR7)), I am seeing this error message, which pops up in the middle of the screen:

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

And Developer Tools shows this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure where to begin fixing this. I've look at other "Graph Element Not Found" questions on StackExchange, as well as the link in the error message.

What about `dataTables-example` is wrong here?

Comment: You're experiencing two independent error messages – one from DataTables, and one from morris. I doubt they have the same root cause. And to help us debug, show use the Network tab of Developer Tools, which contains details on the failing XHR.

Comment: This is what the error shows:    https://imgur.com/a/cx0oU6t  and https://imgur.com/a/8vOjIXQ

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing two independent errors – one from [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) (the enhanced tables jQuery plugin), and one from [morris.js](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) (the graphing library).

## DataTables

The error popup occurs because you're having DataTables load the necessary data from [`ajax.php?content=playerList`](http://bearpk.space/ajax/ajax.php?content=playerList). However, your webserver is not returning valid JSON because of a PHP error message. DataTables receives this as the XHR response:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home1/bearlolz/public_html/ajax/ajax.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
{"data":[]}
```

Because there is garbage before the JSON begins, DataTables cannot parse the response and fails with an error message. Either fix the bug in your PHP that is causing the error, or suppress PHP error reporting with `ini_set("display_errors", 0);`

## morris.js

The console error happens because you have in `dashboard.php`:

```php
<?php $template->scripts(); ?>
```

Which injects into the HTML:

```html
<script src="bin/data/morris-data.js"></script>
```

Which executes [`morris-data.js`](http://bearpk.space/bin/data/morris-data.js), which tries to create graphs on the DOM elements with `id` values of `morris-area-chart`, `morris-donut-chart`, and `morris-bar-chart`. But there are no such elements in the HTML, so the morris library throws an error, which ends up in the console.

Comment: Hi, are you talking about this php error message: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/bearlolz/public_html/ajax/ajax.php on line 14
{"data":[]}                       https://pastebin.com/3AAAPJR7  is dashboard.php code

Comment: @bigtoughguy Yes, that error message. DataTables assumes the entire XHR response is valid JSON, and of course the error message is not. So JSON parsing fails.